# Is the statement ending with "for" considered proper?

Tags: formality

What would be a better and more formal way out of the two below:

```
The capability was not catered for.
```

or

```
We did not cater for this capability.
```

Or perhaps these are fully interchangeable?

Comment: To the person who voted the question down -- thank you. I hope that you upvote the questions as diligently as downvote them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to popular thought, ending a sentence with a preposition is not verboten.  Here is a wonderful (and short) video discussing the issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OLxLK_R6jQ.

However, I would never suggest the use of the preposition "for" with the verb "cater".  My suggested fix:

> We did not provide for this capability.

"This capability was not provided for."  While correct, this is unnecessarily passive in construction anyway.

Comment: Thank you. Your reply did provide an additional insight to the one in response to "When is it appropriate to end a sentence in a preposition?".